# Serialize the creation of user and profile django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an user and his profile through DRF, but I don't find the correct way to do it.

Here's my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='es')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s - %s" % (self.user, self.language)
```

my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')

class Meta:

    model = Profile
    fields = [
    'username',
    'language',
    ]

def create (self, validated_data):

    user = get_user_model().objects.create(username=validated_data['username'])
    user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
    user.save()

    profile = Profile.objects.create(user = user)

    return profile
```

my views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from serializers import ProfileCreateSerializer
from models import Profile

class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):

    model = Profile
    serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import views
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.ProfileCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='crear perfil'),
]
```

if I try to create it shows me this error:

```
Cannot assign "{u'username': u'test'}": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

if i create an user and his profile via admin panel doesn't show me any error.

my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Perfil'
    fk_name = 'user'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I'm using django 1.9.1 and django rest framework 3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need UserSerializer at first place? Change your `ProfileCreateSerializer` to following. It should work

```
class ProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')

   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = [
       'username',
       'language',
       ]

   def create (self, validated_data):
    user = get_user_model().objects.create(username=validated_data['username'])
    user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
    user.save()

    profile = Profile.objects.create(user = user)

    return profile
```

Since the create method is override at your serializer, you need to send the data as a format the serializer process. So, you need to override the POST request at the views and create data as follows :

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    model = Profile
    serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'username': request.data.get('username', None),
            'language': request.data.get('language', None),

        }

        serializer = ProfileCreateSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response( serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: It shows:
Field.to_internal_value() must be implemented.

Comment: Change serializers.field to CharField as above. ```username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')```

Comment: done, now shows me an error just saying key error 'username'

Comment: Can you check your validated_data? You should have 'username' in that validated_data dictionary.

Comment: Fixed already, now show me that Cannot assign "{u'username': u'ddesq'}": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance. Any idea? :|

Comment: I have edited the above code, You need to create profile object and return at serializer.

Comment: Can you share your complete code by editing your question?

Comment: Done, tell me if you need to see anything else, i think thats all.

Comment: You need to change your views.py file to override POST method and send the data in the format serializer recognises. I have posted the sample code for views.py above.

Comment: Still shows must be a "User" instance. I'm reading this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html but i donn't know how implement it here :|